# structure of $R/I$-modules

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $I$ an ideal of $R$ such that $I$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Ann}_R(M)$.
It is clear that $M$ is an $R/I$-module by a well defined structure as follows:

$$R/I\times M \longrightarrow M\quad
\text{via} \quad(r+I)m=rm.$$
Now my questions is:

If $M$ is an $R/I$-module is it true that $I\subseteq \operatorname{Ann}_R(M)$?

Comment: Yes. How do you define the $R$-module structure on $M$?

Comment: By the nutural structure induced from $R \longrightarrow R/I$.

Comment: Sure. So, $xm=0_{R/I}\,m=0$ for all $x\in I$, right?

Comment: I dont understand your mean of $xm=0_{R/I}m$.

Comment: ok got it. its right.

Comment: If $x\in I$, the canonical map $R\to R/I$ maps it to the $0$ element of $R/I$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131419/discussion-between-saeed-yazdani-and-berci).